# Difference between these 2 codes?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance

I was wondering why this piece of JAVA code produces a different output than the same code in C++.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public: 
    A(){
        this->Foo();
    }
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        cout << "A::Foo()" << endl;
    }
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        this->Foo();
    }
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        cout << "B::Foo()" << endl;
    }
};
int main(int, char**)
{
    B objB;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the output:

```
A::Foo()
B::Foo()
```

The JAVA code is:

```
public class Testa {
    public Testa()
    {
        this.Foo();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Testb b = new Testb();
    }
    void Foo()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

}
class Testb extends Testa {
    public Testb()
    {
        this.Foo();
    }
    @Override
    void Foo()
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

This code produces only

```
B
B
```

Why is this output different in this case?

Comment: In C++ you should not call virtual functions in the constructor (or destructor), I don't do much Java, so I won't speak on that.

Comment: Note that in the C++ code you are calling foo from both constructors, while in the Java code you are calling it only from the constructor of Testb.

Comment: Oops, sorry I typed it wrong, one second...

Comment: C++: While executing the constructor of the base A the, virtual of B is not present, hence A shows in the output. After that, in the execution of the constructor of B, the virtual of B is present, hence B shows in the output.

Comment: When you call virtual functions in constructors and destructors, the function that gets called is the one available to the class of that constructor/destructor. So in your case, even though B overrides A's foo. A's foo is what will be called. This is because B is not fully constructed and so its vtable is the same as A's vtable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in the handling of polymorphism during construction. In Java, the dynamic type of the object is that of the derived class right away, allowing you to call member function even before the constructor gets a chance to set the member variables. This is bad.

C++ has a different approach: While the constructor runs, the type of the object considered to be the one of the class that the constructor belongs to. All calls to member functions are resolved statically according to that assumption. Consequently, the constructor of `A` calls `A::foo()`, while the constructor of `B` calls `B::foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

The first part of my answer was given before the Java `Testa` constructor was included.

---

In the Java code, you don't have a `Testa` constructor defined as in your C++ code.  That explains why only one `B` is printed in Java.

But even if you did, to make the code more equivalent:

```
public Testa()
{
   this.Foo();
}
```

It would print

```
B
B
```

Because in Java polymorphism works even when the method is called from the constructor.  But that's not a good idea to do that, because the child part of the object `Testb` will still be uninitialized when the method `Foo` is called in `Testb`.

Comment: Okay cool, you read my mind. So this does not work like this in C++?

Comment: @MattJones no, it doesn't.

Comment: @MattJones I know more Java than C++; I don't know why C++ behaves differently.  But I can verify that it does print `A::Foo()` and `B::Foo()` in C++.